# Assume or Imply?

Tags: vocabulary

There is one sense in which these two words have a similar meaning. What is the difference in this *meaning*, rather the difference in grammatical usage?

A assumes B

> Smoke assumes fire.

This sentence doesn't work.

A implies B

> Smoke implies fire.

If there is smoke, then there is a fire.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=assume+OR+infer+OR+imply

Comment: Flagging as general reference. See the [FAQ#where-can-i-find-answers-to-simple-and-basic-questions] for details.

Comment: @DragonLord Thank you for your diligence.  For the purposes for closing, you should flag only for possible duplicate, migration, or off-topic (as well as the usual spam/offensive).  It is for the community to decide if it is general reference, not the mods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumptions are made by thinking beings. Things that cannot reason cannot make assumptions.

Implications are given by evidence.

> Smoke assumes fire.

This makes no sense because smoke can't assume anything. It is not capable of reasoning.

> Smoke implies fire.

This works because smoke is evidence of fire.

Comment: Yes - I believe OP is being misled by an allowed transferred meaning of _presume_ rather than _assume_ here: **presume** 2. To constitute reasonable evidence for assuming; appear to prove: A signed hotel bill presumes occupancy of a room. (AHD)

Comment: By this logic, one might suppose that *to presuppose* must take a sentient subject, but I see nothing odd about ["smoke presupposes fire"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22smoke+presupposes+fire%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Close. Implications are actually made by [propositions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), not just evidence; _implies_ is the usual English for the logical functor `⊃` (truth table TFTT; pronounced 'horseshoe'; named "material implication"). There are also technical definitions for _[presupposition](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Presuppositiontriggers.pdf)_ and _[entailment](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Predicatetypes.pdf)_.

Comment: I think it works metonymically.

Comment: Sorry, @Mitch, you've lost me there.

Comment: Smoke as an inanimate cannot literally assume things as you point out, but one can personify smoke (I maybe misused metonym, it is too broad). But frankly, that is not what is going on here anyway. What I'm saying is that 'assumes' can work as 'is implied by', for smoke to appear, fire must have occurred, and so logically, fire implies smoke, and thus fire is an assumption from which one can then infer smoke.

Comment: @Mitch, _logically, fire implies smoke, and thus fire is an assumption from which one can then infer smoke_ This is not the case in the above example: If P then Q. Above, you are stating, Q therefore P, which was not part of the logic. If there is smoke around, it must have come from a fire, does not imply that if there is a fire, there must be smoke. The fuel could burn without smoke. **Assume** and **Imply** work in different "directions".

Comment: In maths, **implies** means _guarantees / demands that_. This is not the case in everyday terminology:  **imply** 1. to express or indicate by a hint; suggest (Collins)

Comment: @Mitch: Are you saying that an allowable sense of **assume** is: _to constitute reasonable evidence for assuming_? I can only find this sense defined for **presume** (see above). Have you a dictionary giving this sense for _assume_ too?